# How to split a string into groups of 3 and then print correspondingly to the group?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This question is a duplicate. I know. However, the last answer for this was for python 2.7 and was used in a terminal **and** I have something else I need to incorporate into this.

This is my code:

```py
n = 3

xdict = {
  "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"], "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
  "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"], "Methionine": "AUG", "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
  "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"], "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
  "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"], "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
  "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"], "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"], "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
  "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"], "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"], "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
  "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"], "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"], "Trytophan": "UGG",
  "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"], "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
  "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
}

lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in xdict.items() for k in values}
a = input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")
line = a
line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n) #taken from other answer
print(lookup_dict[line]) #edited from other answer
```

How would I manipulate this code so that if I input something like `UUUUUCUUA` it would print `Phenylalanine Phenylalanine Leucine` (by splitting the string into parts of 3)?

**Examples**

```
a = AUUAUGGUU
Isoleucine Methionine Valine

a = GAAGAGUGU
Glutamic Acid Glutamic Acid Cysteine
```

Comment: Can you give us more examples of outputs?

Comment: the line `line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)` is not doing anything.  You are not saving the resulting list anywhere - e.g. by storing it in a variable: `new_variable = line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can slice `a` into groups of three characters.

```
n = 3

xdict = {
    "Phenylalanine": ["UUU", "UUC"],
    "Leucine": ["UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"],
    "Isoleucine": ["AUU", "AUC", "AUA"],
    "Methionine": "AUG",
    "Valine": ["GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"],
    "Serine": ["UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"],
    "Proline": ["CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"],
    "Threonine": ["ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"],
    "Alanine": ["GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"],
    "Tyrosine": ["UAU", "UAC"],
    "Histidine": ["CAU", "CAC"],
    "Glutamine": ["CAA", "CAG"],
    "Asparagine": ["AAU", "AAC"],
    "Lysine": ["AAA", "AAG"],
    "Asparatic Acid": ["GAU", "GAC"],
    "Glutamic Acid": ["GAA", "GAG"],
    "Cysteine": ["UGU", "UGC"],
    "Trytophan": "UGG",
    "Arginine": ["CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"],
    "Serine": ["AGU", "AGC"],
    "Glycine": ["GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"]
}

lookup_dict = {k: key for key, values in xdict.items() for k in values}
a = 'UUUUUCUUA'  # input("Enter your DNA sequence: ")

for k in [a[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(a), n)]:
    print(lookup_dict[k])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change `list`'s inside `xdict` to `set`'s and use intersection.

```
xdict = {
    "Phenylalanine": {"UUU", "UUC"},
    "Leucine": {"UUA", "CUU", "CUC", "CUA", "CUG", "UUG"},
    "Isoleucine": {"AUU", "AUC", "AUA"},
    "Methionine": {"AUG"},
    "Valine": {"GUU", "GUC", "GUA", "GUG"},
    "Serine": {"UCU", "UCC", "UCA", "UCG"},
    "Proline": {"CCU", "CCC", "CCA", "CCG"},
    "Threonine": {"ACU", "ACC", "ACA", "ACG"},
    "Alanine": {"GCU", "GCC", "GCA", "GCG"},
    "Tyrosine": {"UAU", "UAC"},
    "Histidine": {"CAU", "CAC"},
    "Glutamine": {"CAA", "CAG"},
    "Asparagine": {"AAU", "AAC"},
    "Lysine": {"AAA", "AAG"},
    "Asparatic Acid": {"GAU", "GAC"},
    "Glutamic Acid": {"GAA", "GAG"},
    "Cysteine": {"UGU", "UGC"},
    "Trytophan": {"UGG"},
    "Arginine": {"CGU", "CGC", "CGA", "CGG", "AGG", "AGA"},
    "Serine": {"AGU", "AGC"},
    "Glycine": {"GGU", "GGC", "GGA", "GGG"}
}
```

use `wrap` from `textwrap` to split input.

```
from textwrap import wrap

a = set(wrap("UUUUUAUUC", 3)) # {'UUA', 'UUC', 'UUU'}
print([key for key, value in xdict.items() for _ in value & a])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n) #taken from other answer
```

List comprehension requires [ ] around the loop.

```
[line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]
```

is a list of strings each of length 3. Replace last two lines in your code with following:

```
for s in [line[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(line), n)]:
     print(lookup_dict[s])
```